# I'm getting errors while installing wifi drivers. How can I fix this?

Tags: drivers, wireless

i downloaded Ubuntu Budgie onto my computer and my USB wifi adapter didn't work so I downloaded the driver onto my phone and transfered it over to my computer. Once that happened I tried running the install.sh file but I keep getting this error:

```
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
bash: make: command not found
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
bash: make: command not found
####################################
Compile make driver error: 127
Please check error Mesg
####################################
```

I tried running it normally, with sudo, and with sure but it keeps giving me the errors. I do understand that there are other posts similar to this but I don't understand how to make those specific solutions work with mine.

**EDIT:**
I don't know what I need to do exactly. I have my usb wifi adapter plugged in but my computer isn't registering it so I will do both codes. For `lspci -nnk | grep 0280` nothing happened and for `lsusb` I got:

`Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:5104 Microdia 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 145f:01c1 Trust 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

I don't know if this helps either but the linux driver that I'm supposed to install is called Wsky-AC600-LINUX-Driver which is located in my Downloads directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some other computer, go to this site: https://packages.ubuntu.com/ Select your Ubuntu version; check from the terminal:

```
lsb_release -d
```

And your architecture; either 32- or 64-bit:

```
arch
```

Search for the package *build-essential*. Download it and all its dependencies. The dependencies are indicated by a red dot; in this case, dpkg-dev, g++, gcc, libc6-dev and make. Download these packages, too. Transfer the .deb files to the desktop of the Ubuntu machine. Then, from the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

It may complain that a package is missing a dependency. If so, download that and add it to the desktop and try again.

**EDIT**: If, on the other hand, you have an available ethernet connection, you may quite simply do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

All the needed dependencies, and their dependencies, will be automatically installed.

Footnote: We'd like to confirm the details of your USB wireless as there may be a better way than this lengthy process. Please edit your question to add the result of:

```
lsusb
```

**EDIT2**: Your wireless device is this: 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8812au
sudo dkms build -m 8812au/4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m 8812au/4.2.2
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: Okay so I was downloading the gcc(...).Deb and it gave me the error "package gcc-7 is not installed" so I downloaded the gcc-7 .Deb package but it gave me the error "package libgcc-7-dev is not installed. I don't want to keep downloading multiple packages for each of the multiple packages I have to download. Would it be easier if I can connect to Ethernet...I would have to move my computer to another room but it's okay. And if it's easier how would I do it with Ethernet?

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few momwnts.

Comment: Hey I found another usb wifi adapter that works but it's honestly really slow...like really slow. So I'm ready, with your help, to get down and dirty to fix this problem I'm having. I'm sorry for not responding to you for a while.

Comment: Are you wanting to install a driver for the internal? If so, post the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280` Or to tweak the USB? If so, post the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`

Comment: Okay I edited my original post with the information that you requested.

Comment: Please see my next edit in a few minutes.

Comment: I ran `sudo dkms add ./rtl8812au` and it gave `Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/8812au/4.2.2/source ->
                 /usr/src/8812au-4.2.2

DKMS: add completed.
`  But when I ran `sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au/4.2.2` It gave me an error: `Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2 does not exist.
`

Comment: I found out that I just needed to delete rtl from rtl8812au for the last two commands. After that everything ran good but after restarting the computer, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I will edit my answer to correct for the benefit of the searchers. Please show us: `sudo modprobe 8812au && dmesg | grep 8812`

Comment: I ran it and got `modprobe: FATAL: Module 8812au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic`

Comment: How about: `sudo dkms status` ?

Comment: `8812au, 4.2.2, 4.13.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)`

Comment: It appears that you built it in -36 but are now booted in -37. It should have rebuilt for -37. Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep dkms`

Comment: I ran it but nothing happened

Comment: Please try: `sudo dkms --force install 8812au/4.2.2` and if there are no errors: `sudo modprobe 8812au`

Comment: After running those it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour