# Lenovo Ideapad 720S and Ubuntu 17.10 does not see rtlwifi NIC rtl8821CE

Tags: networking, lenovo, realtek-wireless, ideapad

This system does not see the interface.  I have seen solutions regarding the rtl8821AE device, but I am not sure if that is what I need to do to make this wifi network show up.  The settings reports that there is no wifi card installed.  It looks to me like the modules for rtl8821ae are available, but it doesn't seem to work.  I will continue to search, but I am posting here because I can't figure out exactly what to do.

Comment: lshw shows pci 0 unclaimed with the realtek network unclaimed.

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact device. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: 01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c821]

Comment: I found this:   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379049/realtek-wifi-driver-problem-in-linux-mint-18-2

Comment: The problem is I can't get on the network to add a development environment.  Do I just need the kernel headers?

Comment: Ok, I was able to download and unzip the rtl8821CE source.  But now I need to get a gcc environment installed without a network.  I don't want to download the entiry package tree  So I have to learn how to get the packages with dependencies and make an installation script.  It seems like it should be simpler than this, all I need is gcc to work.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013805/im-getting-errors-while-installing-wifi-drivers-how-can-i-fix-this/1013894#1013894 I'm not quite sure what Ubuntu version you installed that doesn't include headers and build-essential by default. Please note that my link is intended to show how to install build-essential. The remainder of the post deals with a different device.

Answer (score 2):

I purchased a Lenovo Ideapad 720S equipped with an AMD Ryzen 7 processor and a 520Gb SSD and other features.  It was delivered with Windows 10.

There is a very useful disk manager in Windows that allowed me to reduce the size of the Windows partition, maintain the Windows 10 installation and create a dual boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu system. Here is a good link that explains how to set this up: https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

I downloaded Ubuntu 17.10.1 and created a bootable ISO thumb drive.  Booting the Lenovo 720S with this thumb drive installed took a bit of work.  I may try to list the details here but there are a number of youtube videos on how to get the usb drive to show up on the boot menu in the UEFI bios menu.

Once I installed Ubuntu on the new partition there was no network connectivity and the setup menu showed no network interface card installed.  The Realtek drivers are not built into the Ubuntu kernel.

**To correct this problem I downloaded the rtl8821ce source code from github.com and manually downloaded the debian packages from the packages.ubuntu.com artful AMD64 repositories and used dpkg to install them.**

Following this post is the list of packages that I downloaded to enable the build of the rtl8821ce kernel module.  I changed the TopDIR line in the Makefile to point to the rtl8821ce directory where the Makefile resides.  After that I ran:

```
make all
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -a 8821ce
```

That's it, it works fine.  *However, once I was online and updated Ubuntu, the system built a new kernel and I had to rerun the above commands after the system rebooted.*

**build-essential required packages for 17.10.1:**

```
binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu_2.29.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf_2.29.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
binutils-common_2.29.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu_2.29.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
binutils_2.29.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
build-essential_12.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
bzip2_1.0.6-8.1_amd64.deb
cpp-7_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
cpp_7.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
dpkg-dev_1.18.24ubuntu1_all.deb
g++-7_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
g++_7.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
gcc-7-base_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
gcc-7_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
gcc_7.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libacl1_2.2.52-3build1_amd64.deb
libasan4_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libatomic1_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libattr1_2.4.47-2build1_amd64.deb
libbinutils_2.29.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libbz2-1.0_1.0.6-8.1_amd64.deb
libc-dev-bin_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
libc6-dev_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
libc6_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
libcc1-0_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libcilkrts5_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libdb5.3_5.3.28-13.1_amd64.deb
libdpkg-perl_1.18.24ubuntu1_all.deb
libgcc-7-dev_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libgcc1_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libgdbm3_1.8.3-14_amd64.deb
libgmp10_6.1.2+dfsg-1_amd64.deb
libgomp1_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libisl15_0.18-1_amd64.deb
libitm1_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
liblsan0_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
liblzma5_5.2.2-1.3_amd64.deb
libmpc3_1.0.3-2_amd64.deb
libmpfr4_3.1.6-1_amd64.deb
libmpx2_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libpcre3_8.39-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb
libperl5.26_5.26.0-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libquadmath0_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libselinux1_2.7-1_amd64.deb
libstdc++-7-dev_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libstdc++6_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libtsan0_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
libubsan0_7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
linux-libc-dev_4.13.0-37.42_amd64.deb
make-guile_4.1-9.1_amd64.deb
make_4.1-9.1_amd64.deb
patch_2.7.5-1build1_amd64.deb
perl-base_5.26.0-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
perl-modules-5.26_5.26.0-8ubuntu1_all.deb
perl_5.26.0-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
tar_1.29b-2_amd64.deb
xz-utils_5.2.2-1.3_amd64.deb
zlib1g_1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: This is excellent! The suggested fixes always require a temporary internet connection such as an ethernet cable (plenty laptops are ditching these ports nowadays) or a USB Wifi Dongle, so if a user says they don't have access to any of these then we can point them here! :) Kudos to you Mertle - I think this is one of my favourite answers ever!